# Why do I I get undefined in this calculation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I try to loop through the whole array and find out how 'true' they are. Now when I run the function I get some **undefined-result**. :( Why?

```
myArray = [
    {text: 'hola', done: false},
    {text: 'hola', done: true},
    {text: 'hola', done: true},
    {text: 'hola', done: false},
    {text: 'hola', done: true}
  ];

  var howMany = function(myArray){

     var result;
      for (var item in myArray){
          if(myArray.done === true)
            result++;
      }
      return result;
  };


var items =howMany(myArray);
    console.log(items) // I want to see if it's correct
```

Comment: what is the default value for result

Comment: When i'm trying there are already a lot of ans. posted :D You can check this http://jsfiddle.net/8yTKf/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a) You did not initialize the value of `result`:

```
var result = 0;
```

b) This is not how you iterate over the items of an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var item = myArray[i];
    if (item.done === true) { // <-- "item" here, not "myArray"!
        result++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your method of iteration better than using the iteration for-loop (as in question) fixed as in VisioN's answer? Is explicitly defining the counting variable i better in some way?

Comment: @Crashthatch Because array object can be extended with other properties. However, for the current task it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 4):

Check that `result` variable is initialised with `0`. And there is another problem in iteration. You need to use `myArray[item]` to get the value of the object property:

```
if (myArray[item].done === true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try initialising your variable to an actual value: `var result = 0;`

EDIT: Also, as per VisioN's answer, you need to check `myArray[item].done`